# How to print uvm_tlm_analysis_fifo properties with `uvm_info() in UVM?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I'm stuck on the print properties of `uvm_tlm_analysis_fifo` handle with `` `uvm_info() ``.
I made a simple sequence item as below.

```
class simple_sequence_item extends uvm_sequence_item;                            
 
  rand bit[9:0] address;  
  rand bit[31:0] data;   
  rand bit wr_en;  
       bit acc;                                                                

  function new(string name="simple_sequence_item");
    super.new(name);                                            
  endfunction                                                   
 
  `uvm_object_utils_begin(simple_sequence_item)      
  `uvm_field_int(address,UVM_ALL_ON)              
  `uvm_field_int(data,UVM_ALL_ON)
  `uvm_field_int(wr_en,UVM_ALL_ON)
  `uvm_field_int(acc,UVM_ALL_ON)                                           
  `uvm_object_utils_end                                                        
 
  constraint c_sequence_item { data<'d40;             
                                   data>'d1;
                                 }
  constraint c_address{ address<'d500;                                 
                            address>'d0;                                       
                          }                                                    
 
  constraint c_wr_en{
                          wr_en=='d1;
  }           
 
endclass
```

I have implemented with a declaration of `simple_sequence_item` as the below,

```
class apb_scoreboard extends uvm_scoreboard;
 
    simple_sequence_item seq_item;
    `uvm_component_utils(simple_scoreboard)
 
    uvm_tlm_analysis_fifo#(simple_sequence_item) fifo_exp;

...
 
virtual task run_phase( uvm_phase phase);
fifo_exp.get(seq_item);
`uvm_info(get_type_name(), $sformat("fifo_get seq_item from mon in Scoreboard : \n Address=%02h\n data=%02h\n wr_en=%02h\n acc=%02h\n", seq_item.address, seq_item.data, seq_item.wr_en, seq_item.acc, ), UVM_LOW)
endtask
```

But, the problem is that I got `the System task was invoked like a function (it has no return value)` error message during compile.

```
xmelab: *W,DSEMEL: This SystemVerilog design will be simulated as per IEEE 1800-2009 SystemVerilog simulation semantics. Use -disable_sem2009 option for turnin
                                seq_item.address, seq_item.data, seq_item.wr_en, seq_item.acc ), UVM_LOW)
                                                                                                         |
*E,NOTSYF (./apb_scoreboard.sv,46|105): System task was invoked like a function (it has no return value) [2.7.4(IEEE Std 1364-2001)].
```

How to print properties of `uvm_tlm_analysis_fifo` handle with `uvm_info()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$sformat
```

to:

```
$sformatf
```

Note the `f` at the end.  Your code uses the system **task** `$sformat`, which does not return a string.  You need the system **function** `$sformatf`, which does return a string.  This is what the error message is referring to.

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 21.3.3 *Formatting data to a string* for complete details about the syntax.